# Close button not ansering(jQuery on click event) inside popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

I have a problem that seems to be simple but I can't find what's going on. I have a popup with `onClick`, inside menu popup box is showing. I have element on my page that is called popup, and it grows to fill the screen on click by adding `popupActive` class and than using `load()`, it then loads some content from the server. It all works great so far. Then, whan a user clicks on **X** it should remove `popupActive` class and shrink back to original state (this is accomplished with `scale(0)` and `scale(1)`). But instead when I click **X** nothing happenes, console doesn't show any errors, and I tried `console.log("Hello!")` to see if it ever got there (script), but it doesn't show anything.

My code is below.

**HTML**

```
<section id="popup" class="popup"><button class="about-close">X</button</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 1s linear all;
}
.popupActive {
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 99;
    transition: 1s linear all;
}
.about-close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #f74d4e;
    color: #f74d4e;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".li-a").on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#popup").addClass("popupActive").load("Ajax/about.html");
});
$(".about-close").on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello!");
    $(".about-container").remove();
    $("#popup").removeClass("popupActive");
});
```

Comment: please provide html as well

Comment: it's working . i have tested it:- https://jsfiddle.net/0kh6c9sm/

Comment: instead of loading content into the popup element, put a content div inside popup and try loading to that.

Comment: its working whan I'm not loading to popup directly but instead to child div.Thanks a lot!Put something as anser so I could mark it as ansered and give you rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <section id="popup" class="popup"><button class="about-close">X</button>
    <div class="popup-content"></div>
   </section>
```

script:

```
$(".li-a").on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#popup").addClass("popupActive");
         $("#popup .popup-content").load("Ajax/about.html");
    });
    $(".about-close").on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hello!");
        $("#popup .popup-content").remove();
        $("#popup").removeClass("popupActive");
    });
```

Comment: Note, this will attach a new handler every time the modal opens. Try multiple open closes, and watch how many "Hello"'s you get in the console. May not be a big deal if you are not expecting many open/closes.

Comment: Its simple page,just something for fun,not many visits or open/closes,static,simple content...

Comment: @arbuthnott, I didn't understand. The close is binded only once globally. It is not binded inside click of .li-a

Comment: all I did is adding a div inside popup and loading into it,in jQuery $("#popup div").  ....all the same,thanks,simple and fast fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `load` method is asynchronous - that means it may not be finished adding the internal html before you try to attach the click-handler that closes the modal.

You could attach the click handler in the callback for load (like `.load("Ajax/about.html", function() { /* attach it here */ })`), but I think a better solution would be to attach the listener higher up, just once even before the modal loads:

```
$("#popup").on('click', '.about-close',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello!");
    $(".about-container").remove();
    $("#popup").removeClass("popupActive");
});
```

That code just needs to run once when the initial page DOM is ready.

Comment: This one doesnt work,just tryed it,to be hionest Jose Tuttu solution is working.Thanks anyway :)